# Convert high resolution images into PDFs for print

Tags: print-design, pdf, software-recommendation

How does one create a single pdf file of several high resolution images to send to printer (For free)? I have been using Canva's very simple process just for this but it sometimes overlaps images during the downloading process.

Comment: It would be easier if you screenshot us ?

Comment: Can I ask you why you want to put the high resolution images in a PDF?  Are you laying them out in a document? What kind of printing method is going to be involved? Digital? Offset Lithography? Please add more details so you can be given a relevant answer.

Comment: Are you making a collage? or one image per page?

Answer (score 1):

There are web sites such as http://jpg2pdf.com/ which are designed to convert several images to a PDF.

Beyond that, explaining what software you have available may aide in receiving more detailed answers.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to Adobe Bridge, that has a feature called 'Output' where you can select a number of images and it will generate a PDF. Plus you get a lot of options on how to layout this PDF and its all automatic. Also works with large folders if you need it to.

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend you to download and use InDesign's trial version. It won't cost you a penny and you can have 30 days with it. Go to adobe.com for more details and download links.